# How the runtime address binding works in operating system?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, system

There are three types of adress binding schemes:

1. Compile time address binding: The symbolic addresses are converted to actual memory address during compilation and the loader just loads the program into the memory address.
2. Loadtime address binding:- In this the symblolic adresses are converted to relocatable addresses by the linker and the loader resloves the relocateable addresses to physical addresses using relocation register.
3. Runtime adress binding:- I am not able to understand this part.If the linker creates relocatable adresses. But then who loads the process to the memory .(I know loader does this ) But if loader loads the process it becomes load time address binding. My main question is where from the loader gets the address that where it should load the process in the main memory during runtime. And also  to put a process in running state atleast one module of the program should be in the main memory.Who decides at what address this first module will get loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is a bit off:

1. *static* binding assigns the addresses to the image when it is linked.  Confusingly unix calls linking loading; thus the link-editor is ld (loader).  Static binding can be accomplished by an assembler if there are no unresolved references, thus the *a.out* standard.
2. When an image is *exec*’d, any residual unresolved references may be resolved by a *dynamic linker*.  The *dynamic linker* can be a simple library that looks at the unresolved symbols in your executable image, and matches them up to some set of *shared objects* which it maps into your process’s address space.  Not all unresolved references need be resolved at this point; only the *data* ones.  Since procedures are entered by jumping to an address, they can be resolved *lazily* as the process calls the procedures.  Effectively the procedure is initially interposed upon by one which finds the actual implementation, then makes it so subsequent calls go straight to it.  Look up *GOT* (Global Offset Table) and *PLT* (Procedure Linkage Table) if you want the nitty gritty.  Few want to.
3. When a process binds to a shared object (via dlopen() and family), it goes through a somewhat similar operation as (2), but typically not via a symbolic interface, but rather a *class-like* interface, where the dynamically attached library has an init function which provides a known layout data structure for accessing it.  From that, any level of complexity can be readily constructed.